# Hamming distance and CRC

Tags: crc, hamming-distance

How to find the Hamming distance of a code generated by a certain CRC?

Assume that I have a generating polynomial of order, say, 4 and 11 bits of data.

How to compute the HD basing only on these information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to pad your results with zeros making both values 11bits long. Computing an XOR on the two bit strings and counting the ones should yield the hamming distance for your data set.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Yup, but assume Ive got 11 bits of data (2^11 possible and correct words) and I append CRC bits found with use of a certain polynomial. What will be the Hamming distance then?

Comment: I would say you have two options... Keep the Hamming distance without the CRC bits and if you need to recalculate just strip them out. Or append the CRC bits to the 11 bit value and then calculate the Hamming distance... Would that work for you?

Comment: Do you have an idea how to calculate the Hamming distance on paper?